# Shell Extract Text Before Digits in a String

Tags: string, shell, text, digits

I've found several examples of extractions before a single character and examples of extracting numbers, but I haven't found anything about extracting characters before numbers.

**My question:**
Some of the strings I have look like this:

```
NUC320 Syllabus Template - 8wk
SLA School Template - UL
CJ101 Syllabus Template - 8wk
TECH201 Syllabus Template - 8wk
Test Clone ID17
```

In cases where the string doesn't contain the data I want, I need it to be skipped. The desired output would be:

```
NUC-320
CJ-101
TECH-201
```

`SLA School Template - UL` & `Test Clone ID17` would be skipped.

**I imagine the process being something to the effect of:**

1. Extract text before `" "`
2. Condition - Check for digits in the string
3. Extract text before digits and assign it to a variable `x`
4. Extract digits and assign to a variable `y`
5. Concatenate `$x"-"$y` and assign to another variable `z`

**More information:**
The strings are extracted from a line in a couple thousand text docs using a loop. They will be used to append to a hyperlink and rename a file during the loop.

**Edit:**

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # my files are named 1.txt through 9999.txt i both 
    # increments the loop and sets the filename to be searched

    i=1

    while [ $i -lt 10000 ]
    do
        x=$(head -n 31 $i.txt | tail -1 | cut -c 7-)
        if [ ! -z "$x" -a "$x" != " " ]; then
# I'd like to insert the hyperlink with the output on the
# same line (1.txt;cj101 Syllabus Template - 8wk;www.link.com/cj101)
            echo "$i.txt;$x" >> syllabus.txt
    #   else
    #       rm $i.txt
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        sleep .1
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed for printing lines starting with capital letters followed by digits. It also adds a `-` between them:

```
sed -n 's/^\([A-Z]\+\)\([0-9]\+\) .*/\1-\2/p' input
```

*Gives:*

```
NUC-320
CJ-101
TECH-201
```

Comment: Nicely done, but you're using _GNU_ Sed syntax - `\+` isn't portable; using `\{1,\}` instead makes the command portable: `sed -n 's/^\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\) .*/\1-\2/p' input`.

Comment: I'm struggling with implementing this as whats being edited is a variable rather than a string from a file. I'm editing my question for a better picture.

Comment: Got this to work by using `echo "$x" | sed -n 's/^\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\) .*/\1-\2/p'` so it would modify the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX-compliant `awk` solution:

```
awk '{ if (match($1, /[0-9]+$/)) print substr($1, 1, RSTART-1) "-" substr($1, RSTART) }' \
  file | 
    while IFS= read -r token; do
      # Process token here (append to hyperlink, ...)
      echo "[$token]"
    done
```

- `awk` is used to extract the reformatted tokens of interest, which are then processed in a *shell* `while loop`.
- `match($1, /[0-9]+$/)` matches the 1st whitespace-separated field (`$1`) against extended regex `[0-9]+$`, i.e., matches only if the fields ends in one or more digits.
- `substr($1, 1, RSTART-1) "-" substr($1, RSTART)` joins the part before the first digit with the run of digits using `-`, via the special `RSTART` variable, which indicates the 1-based character position where the most recent `match()` invocation matched.

Comment: I'm struggling with implementing this as whats being edited is a variable rather than a string from a file. I'm editing my question for a better picture.

Comment: @Anderb7583: My pleasure; glad to hear you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 ~/[0-9]/{sub(/...$/,"-&",$1);print $1}' file

NUC-320
CJ-101
TECH-201
```